# Center buttons in a vertical alignment

Tags: java, button, boxlayout

I am currently building a project which include a couple of buttons, and I am trying to vertically align these buttons in the center of the panel. I am also trying to make them the exact same size (like new Dimension(15, 100)).

For the part where I am trying to center the buttons I have tried to use BoxLayout, which works fine until I try to make the buttons the same size.. I have tried to use

```
myButton.setSize(new Dimension(15, 100))
myButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(15, 100));
myButton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(15, 100));
```

and for the BoxLayout part, I am using this code piece

```
buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

which works quite well, but it is the centering/size-specification that wont work for me..

Comment: Why not simply put the JButtons into a JPanel that uses a `GridLayout(0, 1, 0, ??)` where ?? is a number that represents the desired space between buttons? The first 0, and 1 parameters means one column with a variable number of rows.

Comment: You probably don't really want them a fixed size in pixels once someone runs your application on a computer with a different screen resolution. @HovercraftFullOfEels suggestion can help with that.